# What is the default return value of a VB6 function?

Tags: vb6

While working away on an old piece of code I came across something like this:-

```
Public Function MyFunc (some parameters) As Single

    If some condition Then
        MyFunc = calculate some value
    Else
        MyFunc = MyFunc
    End If

End Function
```

I'm rather hoping to regularise the second leg of that test; would I be right in assuming the returned value is `0.0` if `some condition` is `false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for a function with a defined return type then the default return value is the default for that type (0 for numerics etc) just as if the code contained a `Dim MyFunc as Single` at the top.

If no type is specified and no value is implicitly returned, then the `Empty` value is returned.

Comment: "No type specified" is an implicit specification of Variant type.